# How to apply Drupal's Ckeditor HTML filters when manually saving node fields?

Tags: drupal-8

I have written a custom content import script for Drupal 8, which imports content from a JSON export from another website.

My ckeditor fields have pretty basic HTML filtering and for example replaces `<i>` statements for `<em>` statements and `<b>` for `<strong>`.
Now when I save my HTML into a field with such settings my HTML works fine for `<p>` and `<ul>` statements, but `<i>` tags are not being displayed:

```
$html = '<p><i>Italic text</i> and some <b>bold</b> text</p>';
$node->set('field_some_html', ['value' => $html, 'format' => 'basic_html']);
```

It now renders as:

```
<p>Italic text and some bold text</p>
```

When I then edit the node, while editing I do see the text in cursive or bold.
When I save the node everything is corrected. The statements have now been converted.

It now renders as:

```
<p><em>Italic text</em> and some <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
```

So my question is: how do I fix this? How do I apply the filters to my HTML input before saving the node to the database?

**Update 1** After some more investigation I found FilterFormat. Now I tried this:

```
$html = '<p><i>Italic text</i> and some <b>bold</b> text</p>';

$filter_format = FilterFormat::load($format);
$filters = $filter_format->filters();

/* @var \Drupal\filter\Plugin\Filter\FilterHtml $filter */
foreach($filters as $filter) {
  $html = $filter->process(is_string($html) ? $html : $value->getProcessedText(), 'nl');
}

die($html->getProcessedText());
```

However, this does the opposite of what I want to achieve. This returns the HTML stripped from `<i>` and `<b>` tags.
I think I may be close to the solution though...